# Confusion matrix - strange numeric output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, svm, confusion-matrix

I am using SVM for data classification. After classification I want to show confusion matrix, but numbers are in bad form.

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn import svm

clf_svm = svm.SVC()
.
.
.
n = clf_svm.predict(x_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, n)
plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cbar=False)
plt.xlabel("predicted")
plt.ylabel("true")
```

Output:
[image]

Why is output in format 2.9e+02, 1.9e+02? The size of the training data is 568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

The [default annotation format](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) for `heatmap` is `.2g` which means a general format with 2 precision bytes. Since these numbers require 3 bytes in their string representation this format will round and display in scientific notation. Use `g` alone which defaults to a precision of 6:

```
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cbar=False, fmt='g')
```